# how to handle very long SQL INSERT statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I am using the following (python) code to generate a (MySQL) SQL INSERT statement (there are more columns, I left them out for simplicity):

```
mylist = [('1', '2', '3'),
          ('4', '5', '6'),
          .
          .
          .
          ('7', '8', '9')]

sql_statement = "insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values "

for i in mylist:
    if sql_statement == "insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values ":
        # append this for the 1st element
        sql_statement += "(" + i[0] + ", " + i[1] + ", " + i[2] + ")"
    else:
        # append this for everything else
        sql_statement += ", (" + i[0] + ", " + i[1] + ", " + i[2] + ")"
```

which results in a string like the following:

```
sql_statement = "insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), ... (7, 8, 9)"
```

I then use `sql_statement` to execute the sql statement.

the issue with this approach is that the `sql_statement` string is getting to long and the insert does not consider all data.

any suggestions how to handle this?

**UPDATE:** *prepared statement* is the way to go. with that the (python) code looks like this:

```
sql_statement = "insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values (%s, %s, %s)"

for i in mylist:
    cursor.execute(sql_statement, i)
```

Comment: instead of inline query, create the stored procedure and pass parameter to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the python library you are using supported prepared parameterized queries? I've found the performance difference between multi-value inserts such as this and repeated executions of prepared statements (in .Net at least) to be minimal in all but extreme cases. (In those cases, a mix of the two is optimal.)

Alternatively, just keep track of your query length, execute before it gets too big, and reinitialize the string & continue until all rows are handled.

Answer (score 1):

Create a transaction and do insert one by one. and finally commit it. So only in one call all insert operation commit.